# Can't connect mlab to now.sh

Tags: javascript, node.js, mlab

I've just finished one of React Full-Stack Course on the Udemy. Resulting project I deployed to heroku. Everything went ok, I had access to my db, except for authorization, but it's never mind.

I wanted to use another platform - now.sh. Test pages work on now.sh perfectly. But then it comes to connecting to db, I have the problems.

I created db for the project on mlab, and tried to connect it by "now secret add db ".

When I deploy it, I get  the error:

> [0] MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

I understand, it tries to connect through localhost. For testing I tried to remove local config and leave just settings for production (env.process.MONGODB_URI etc). After that I got undefined for remote host.

I think, the problem is in uncorrect connecting to mlab.

Could you tell me how I ca fix it?

My config.js:

```
const config = {
  production: {
    SECRET: process.env.SECRET,
    DATABASE: process.env.MONGODB_URI
  },
  default: {
    SECRET: 'SUPERSECRETPASSWORD123',
    DATABASE: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/booksShelf'

  }
}

exports.get = function get(env){
  return config[env] || config.default
}
```

part of server.js

```
 const express = require('express');
 const config = require('./config/config').get(process.env.NODE_ENV)
 const app = express();

 mongoose.connect(config.DATABASE)

....
....
....

 const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

 app.listen(port, ()=>{
   console.log('server running')
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the other place.

The thing was I needed to config my now.json like this:

```
 {
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "production",
    "MONGODB_URI": "@db"
  }
}
```

And that is it. Everything works.